# How to mock Angular HttpClient response within test of observable stream?

Tags: angular, rxjs, jasmine, jasmine-marbles, httptestingcontroller

I have an observable that ultimately triggers a call to Angular HttpClient.  I need to mock the response from the HttpClient, but I'm at a loss how to do it within the context of the TestScheduler run method.  Say I have the following test:

```js
it('observable should trigger call to HttpClient', () => {

    scheduler.run(helpers => {
        const { expectObservable, cold } = helpers;
        const transferObservable = cold('-a-', { a: someInput });
        transferService.value$ = transferObservable;

        sut = new MyService(transferService, apiService);
        const expectedMarble = '-a-';
        const expectedValues = { a: expectedData };
        expectObservable(sut.data$).toBe(expectedMarble, expectedValues);
    });
});
```

Values emitted on `transferObservable` cascade to a `switchMap` call to a service which in turn sends a GET request via Angular HttpClient; the resulting value is emitted from `sut.data$`.

I've tried placing following lines at various places within and outside the scheduler.run method, but I always get the same error: `Expected one matching request for criteria "Match URL: http://foo", found none.`

```js
const request = httpMock.expectOne(`http://foo`);
request.flush(expectedContract);
```

Roughly where and how would I mock a single call to `http://foo` and flush `expectedData` as the desired response?

**EDIT** Stripped-down `beforeEach` setup showing configuration of `HttpTestingController`:

```js
beforeEach(() => {

    scheduler = new TestScheduler((actual, expected) => {
        expect(actual).toEqual(expected);
    });

    transferService = jasmine.createSpyObj<TransferService>(['value$']);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
        declarations: [],
        providers: [],
        schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    });

    httpMock = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
});
```

**EDIT 2**: Screenshot of HttpClient instance from within my service when debugging.

[image]

**EDIT 3**: Stackblitz for issue [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-unit-testing-examples-rb3hnj).  The failing test `contract$ should return contract` is the one of interest.

Comment: Are you using `HttpTestingController`? Can you show your setup for it?

Comment: @wlf I am; see edits above.

Comment: The `expectOne` and `flush` lines should be OK just before `const expectedMarble = '-a-';`. Might be something else going on, can you verify (console.log or debug) that the http call is being made in your service? Also try remove the `-` around your marble data ie: `-a-` => `a`

Comment: @wlf Removing the dashes has no effect.  I have verified that a testing handler appears to be getting injected into my service (see edit above).  When I comment out `expectOne` and `flush` I get log messages up to the point of the actual HTTP call; however when uncomment them I get no log messages at all.  It is as if they are somehow preventing a subscription.

Comment: You could try creating a stack blitz for external debugging - you can fork from this one which has karma running, just go the preview to see the results.

Comment: @wlf Yes, seems it's getting about time to do that.  Give me some time - it may have to be an evening or weekend project.  For now, I'm proceeding without unit tests.  :0

Comment: Link to stack blitz you can modify: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-with-jasmine-f3vgbg?file=app%2Fresize-test.component.spec.ts

Comment: Are you running the test in `fakeAsync`?

Comment: @WillAlexander I am not; is that recommended for this use case?

Comment: I believe it's necessary so that you can call `tick()` and "pretend" that time has passed and the subscription has emitted

Comment: @wlf Added Stackblitz; see edits above.  Also @WillAlexander, I tried adding `fakeAsync()` and `tick()` without an observable change in behavior (not reflected in the StackBlitz link above).

Comment: I looked at your stackblitz for some time but didn't get too far. Main problem is if you look at the console you are getting a `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pipe')` error which is preventing further execution of your test (and the failure). For some reason the `MyService` constructor gets called twice, the first time a real instance of `TransferService` is injected, the second time your mock is injected. When it runs the test it seems to use the former, which causes the error as there is no `value$` defined, so no `pipe` on it.

Comment: @wlf I updated the Stackblitz to initialize `TransferService.value$`; however I don't think that is/was the issue because `value$` is mocked in the test envmt, and the test `url$ should return url` has always passed.  In any case, the error is gone now and the `contracts$ should return contract` test still fails for the same reason.